# using a while loop to print randoms without repeats

Tags: python

I'm working with the following:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
list2 = ["l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"]
list3 = ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

sections = 3
start = 0

while start < sections:
        print(random.sample(list1, k=1))
        print(random.sample(list2, k=1))
        print(random.sample(list3, k=1))
        start = start + 1
```

and ideally I would like to get something like this:

```
['a', 'n', 'z']
['c', 'm', 'v']
['k', 'q', 'y']
```

The strings within each of the lists can be longer or shorter depending on relevant input *and* the "sections" variable can also vary so neither are static.

Comment: You may want to use `random.choice()`.

Comment: remove the item that you sampled by using the list.remove() function

Comment: furthermore you should use a for loop instead of a while loop: for _ in range(sections): ...

Comment: All of that is great input, thanks! How do I go about referencing the printed item for the remove function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that elements are unique, you can first take a sample of k=sections elements from each list, then `zip` them:

```
from random import sample

list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
list2 = ["l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"]
list3 = ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

data = [list1, list2, list3]
sections = 3
chosen = [sample(lst, sections) for lst in data]
out = list(zip(*chosen))
print(out)
# [('h', 'q', 't'), ('a', 'l', 'x'), ('j', 'o', 'z')]
```

and if you really want to have lists instead of tuples:

```
out = [list(tup) for tup in out]
print(out)
# [['h', 'q', 't'], ['a', 'l', 'x'], ['j', 'o', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pick the element from the list and then delete it so you are never gonna pick that again, if you want to keep track of the deleted elements use 2 copies of the same list, a master copy and one copy in which you can delete elements.